# Searching for specific character in string with static method

Tags: java, static, boolean

I have to make a program that counts the number of the letter B in a string. I got that part already, but it also requires me to use a static method that returns true or false based on if the string has any Bs in it and i really don't see how to fit that part in.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountB {

// write the static method “isThisB” here
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
String w = keyboard.nextLine();
int count=0;
for (int i=0; i<w.length(); i++)
{
    if (w.charAt(i)=='B'||w.charAt(i)=='b')
    {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of B and b: "+ count);
}
}
```

Comment: Well, first create the static method. What do you think the method signature should be?

Comment: Select the expression you want to turn into a method and press CTRL+ALT+M on your keyboard to extract the method (on IntelliJ, other IDEs have different hot keys)

Comment: Man. StackOverflow sucks. People just write out homework, and for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
static boolean check(String str){
    if(str.indexOf('B')>0 || str.indexOf('b')>0 )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What if B is the first/only character? did you mean `>= 0` ?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But i forgot to mention that the parameter has to be a char. I'm changing some things to see if i can make it work

Answer (score 2):

```
private static boolean hasAnyB(String str) {
   return str.contains("B") || str.contains("b");
}
```

Comment: In the text description user told: "it also requires me to use a static method that returns true or false based on if the string has any Bs in it and i really don't see how to fit that part in". And that's what the code posted does.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `matches()` method, which uses regex:

```
private static boolean hasB(String str) {
    return str.matches(".*[bB].*");
}
```

Using regex is a near way to handle mixed case issues.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah but if you read the text he's having problems with is "hasB" method: *but it also requires me to use a static method that returns true or false based on if the string has any Bs in it **and i really don't see how to fit that part in.***

Answer (score 1):

Just Deploy all coding inside a `static` method that's it

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  methodOne("Pass string over here");
}

public static boolean methodOne(String s)
{
   return s.contains("B");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the count of `b` or `B` you can do

```
int bCount = w.replaceAll("[^Bb]", "").length();
```

If you have to use a hasB method you could do it like this, though its pretty inefficient and longer than it needs to be

```
int count = 0;
for(String ch: w.split("")) // one character at a time.
    if(hasB(ch))
       count++;
```

Comment: this is exactly the OP wants +1

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean hasAnyB(String str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().contains("b");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest i could think.

```
static boolean isThisB(String s, int count) {
    for(int i=0; i<s.lenght(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c == 'b' || c == 'B')
            count ++;
    }

    return count > 0;
}
```