# Java - pass by value

Tags: java

I was trying something with Integer, and output is freaking me out.

```
public class CountB
{

  public static boolean returnBool(String w, Integer count)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++)
     {
         if (w.charAt(i) == 'B' || w.charAt(i) == 'b')
        {
       count++;
        }
     }

    if (count > 0)
      return true;
    return false;
   }

  // write the static method “isThisB” here
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   //   System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
   String w = "fgsfbhggbB";//keyboard.nextLine();
   Integer count = new Integer(0);
   System.out.println(returnBool(w, count));
   System.out.println("Number of B and b: " + count);
  }
}
```

Now, `Integer` being a wrapper class of `int`, and `count` being its object, when I pass `count` from main to `returnBool`, value of `count` becomes 3, so it returns `true`, as java is pass by value `count` object value should change in `main` method also, but in `main` `count` prints 0.

I want to understand why this is happening?

Comment: Java is always [**pass by value**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/2024761) (Period)

Comment: `Integer` objects are immutable.  Whenever you think you might be changing the value of an `Integer`, what you're _really_ doing is getting a new one.

Comment: You should just return the count.  Java doesn't support pass by reference, never has.  You can simulate it but it is ugly and I suggest you read the answers given in the last question which shows you how you should do this.

Comment: Sorry I confused you for this person who ask about the same homework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855327/searching-for-specific-character-in-string-with-static-method/19855458

Comment: Yeah I know, java is pass by value, somehow reference was in mind and I typed pass by ref. @Marko has explained what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`count++` is just a convenience for

```
count = Integer.valueOf(count.intValue()+1)
```

After this operation, your local variable `count` (in `returnBool`) refers to another object, and the local variable in your `main` method keeps pointing to the initial object. You haven't achieved pass-by-reference.

As for Java semantics, there are two similar concepts which are easy to confuse: Java's pass-by-value of object references (in essence, pointers), and true pass-by-reference. Your example stresses this difference.

Comment: I think that tere isn't pass by reference in Java!

Comment: You think right: there isn't.

Comment: Solution would be to create a class with an Integer in it and pass the class to the method. In the method, override/update the Integer reference inside the class. When exiting the method, the class will hold the new Integer object.

Comment: Another solution is to use "global variables"

Comment: You have a problem and think "I know, I'll use global variables". Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 1):

Java passes the class Integer by Value and not by Reference. If you want to pass it by Reference you'll need an other class like `org.apache.commons.lang.mutable.MutableInt` from Apache Commons library

Comment: Actually it passes the Reference by value. The reference gets updated inside the method, but the initial reference outside the class still references the old object.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. I only know that the Java Integer class is immutable.

Comment: Or you can pass an `int[] count = { 0 };`

Answer (score 0):

There is no pass-by-reference in java. Method parameters are passed by value but that value may be a reference to an object. If the passed object is mutable the changes on it will affect the object outside the method since the object is the same in and out. Integer objects are immutable.
You can pass int[1] or AtomicReference or AtomicInteger or any other object that contains a mutable integer value.

This is your code adapted to AtomicInteger

```
public class CountB
{

  public static boolean returnBool(String w, AtomicInteger count)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++)
     {
         if (w.charAt(i) == 'B' || w.charAt(i) == 'b')
        {
       count.incrementAndGet();
        }
     }

    if (count.intValue() > 0)
      return true;
    return false;
   }

  // write the static method “isThisB” here
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   //   System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
   String w = "fgsfbhggbB";//keyboard.nextLine();
   AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
   System.out.println(returnBool(w, count));
   System.out.println("Number of B and b: " + count);
  }
}
```